# More efficient way to write this if/else

Tags: javascript

I wrote a little check for an input field that counts the length and makes sure it is the proper amount.  It gets complex because it needs to allow either 9 digits or 1 letter and 5 digits.  The way I have it now works but the code hurts my brain, I would like to see what a more elegant solution would look like for this, maybe using ternary and/or switch?

So a little part of the not so pretty that I have in place now :

```
if (len !== 9) {
    if (len == 1) {
        y.hide();
        n.show();
        valInput.text("You need 8 more numbers");
    } else {
        if (len == 2) {
            y.hide();
            n.show();
            valInput.text("You need 7 more numbers");
        } else {
            if (len == 3) {
                y.hide();
                n.show();
                valInput.text("You need 6 more numbers");
            } else {
                if (len == 4) {
                    y.hide();
                    n.show();
                    valInput.text("You need 5 more numbers");
                } else {
                    if (len == 5) {
                        y.hide();
                        n.show();
                        valInput.text("You need 4 more numbers");
                    } else {
                        if (len == 6) {
                            y.hide();
                            n.show();
                            valInput.text("You need 3 more numbers");
                        } else {
                            if (len == 7) {
                                y.hide();
                                n.show();
                                valInput.text("You need 2 more numbers");
                            } else {
                                if (len == 8) {
                                    y.hide();
                                    n.show();
                                    valInput.text("You need 1 more number");
                                } else {
                                    if (len > 9) {
                                        y.hide();
                                        n.show();
                                        valInput.text("Order number must be 9 digits");
                                        // gt 9
                                    }
                                    // 8
                                }
                                // 7
                            }
                            // 6
                        }
                        // 5
                    }
                    // 4
                }
                // 3
            }
            // 2
        }
        // 1
    }
    // this is not equal to 9
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the answers! Lots of good stuff, I will accept my favorite after I play for a while.  To clarify what happens when the proper requirements are met then the submit button fades in but not until it is validated.  Not sure if it is relevant but will mention that the function also runs as "live type" so the message with the count is returned after each `.keyup()`

Comment: try to use `switch`. Btw, you can merge them to one single if..else...: if (len < 9) {
    y.hide();
    n.show();
    valInput.text("You need " + (9 - len) + " more numbers");
}

Comment: Textbook example of when to use `switch` :D

Comment: For sure use `switch`, but even without it why is this such a monstrosity? There is also an `else if`...

Comment: This is not a textbook example of when to use switch. This is a textbook example of when to program with parameters and variables instead of checking magic numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. @jon this is just a small piece of the beast, believe me it is much more monstrous than this.. I will rewrite with switch then if that is the consensus, I was thinking might be a way to even avoid that since all that changes is the integer

Comment: @Zac: No, actually it *looked* like a `switch` but then we noticed that all the blocks are saying the exact same thing. So all you want is an `if/else` and a subtraction to get rid of almost all of that.

Comment: Remember this is programmer efficiency! Unless in a tight loop, The performance difference between this and the other answers is very small.

Comment: @Zac i think my answer might be the best one :p

Comment: @ByronWhitlock thanks and understood.  I just am trying to learn to write better code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use switch, you can do something like this:

```
if (len < 9) {
    y.hide();
    n.show();
    valInput.text("You need " + (9 - len) + " more number(s)");
}
else if (len > 9) {
    y.hide();
    n.show();
    valInput.text("Order number must be 9 digits");
}
else {
    // all good here...
}
```

And if you don't like the `"number(s)"` part, just check if len is not 1, and add that `"s"` to the `"number"`.

Comment: +1, I would use `if (len && len < 9)` to make sure it's a non-zero number.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Agreed, but 0 < 9 and we assume `len` is a proper integer derived from element count.

Comment: @Shomz why have the `else` then?

Comment: @progenhard `else` is when `len` equals 9 (if it's needed in the code - the OP doesn't seem too comfy with JS, so I included that as well)

Comment: @Shomz thanks hahaa i edited my code to fix that. Didn't realize he was looking for `len == 9`

Comment: Thanks! This looks good. I updated to try and make it a little clearer what I am doing but I think I can run with this and get a little more comfy ;)

Comment: @Zac You're welcome. Whenever you see a lot of repeating code, ask yourself if you could optimize it somehow (and in 99% cases, you can). Good luck on your JS journey, never stop learning! :)

Comment: Indeed.. out here in Seattle be nice if I could get something DRY ;)

Answer (score 4):

As those look all the same why not use this:

```
if (len !== 9) {
    var diff = 9 - len;
    var value = ( 0 < diff ? "You need " + diff + " more numbers" : "Order number must be 9 digits" );
    y.hide();
    n.show();
    valInput.text(value);
}
```

Comment: `if (len !== 9) is true for 0` and that's why it's better to use `if (len && len < 9)`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera It's not defined what should happen, when the value is `0`. The code will give: `You need 9 more numbers`, which might be desired.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should calculate the remaining characters through javascript, since that's the only difference in all the other if else branches, so you can do something like this and would be much more readable:

```
if (len !== 9) {
    y.hide();
    n.show();
    if (len > 9) {
        valInput.text("Order number must be 9 digits");
    }
    else{
        var remaining = 9 - len;
        valInput.text("You need " + remaining + " more numbers");
    }
}
```

Comment: All good, except I'd go an extra step and get rid of that remaining variable - it's really not needed.

Answer (score 3):

**In your particular case** it looks like the validation is simple enough for something like this:

```
function validate(len) {
    var msg;
    if (len == 9)
        return true;
    y.hide(); /* no need to duplicate these calls in each condition */
    n.show();
    if (len < 9)
        msg = 'You need ' + (9-len) + ' more number' + (len == 1 ? '' : 's') + '.';
    else
        msg = 'You entered ' + (len-9) + ' number' + (len == 1 ? '' : 's') + ' too many.;
    valInput.text(msg);
    return false;

}
```

*Comment:* `===` should be saved for when needed, not just to be fancy! Unfortunately so many are taught to avoid double equals rather than actually understanding its useful and helpful extra features like type conversion. In this situation there is no reason whatsoever to use triple equals.

**But in general**, such as if your sequence of conditionals does something more significant than alert a sequence of messages varying only by a consecutive integer, then use `switch`...

```
switch (len) {
case 1:

/* handle this case */;
    y.hide();
    n.show();
    valInput.text("You need 8 more numbers");
    break;
/* make sure to end case 1 with a break; */

case 2:
    y.hide();
    n.show();
    valInput.text("You need 7 more numbers");
    break;
/* make sure to end every case with a break; */

...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this to:

```
  if (len !== 9) {
      valInput.text("You need " +  (9 -len ) + " more numbers");
       y.hide();
      n.show();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why even use a `switch` or a huge `if`?

```
if(len == 9){
    // do stuff.
}else{
    y.hide();
    n.show();
    if(9 > len)
         valInput.text("You need " + (len - 9) + " less numbers");
    else 
         valInput.text("You need " + (9 - len) + " more numbers");
    valInput.text("Order number must be 9 digits");
}
```

Just declare the range of the values you want then `concatenate` the string.

Answer (score 0):

the shortest alternative:

```
(y.hide(), n.show(), valInput.text(
     len < 9 &&  "You need " + (9-len) + " more digits"
  || len > 9 && "too many ("+ (len-9) + ") digits" 
  || "ok!"
));
```